# catalina.out shows old tomcat version despite updating CATALINA_HOME

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9, catalina

Upgraded CATALINA_HOME from 9.0.75 to 9.0.82.
CATALINE_HOME shows newer version 9.0.82.
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3iHC.png)
CATALINA_BASE logs shows older version 9.0.75
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWoML.png)

Catalina.out shall show newer version.